# Adding delay or something between hundred of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node for requesting app details from another website but the problem i'm facing is, it sends hundreds ( or maybe thousands ) of request, and then I get error and I receive nothing.

Read comments in code for info...

```
// I'm reading links from another file using 'fs'
fs.readFile('./google_apps/GAME_ACTION.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    // creating a empty array
    var promiseStack = [];

    for (var index in obj['GAME_ACTION']) {
        var linksArray = obj['GAME_ACTION'][index];
        linksArray.forEach( function(link, index) {
            var appID = link.match(/id=.*/g)
            var instr = appID.toString();

            var appIDSliced = instr.slice(3)
            // Here appIDSliced is ID, which is sliced from a link
            // there are thousands on link in this file which I opened

            console.log('sending') // for testing purpose

            // here i'm pushing promises into that empty array
            // store.app({id: appIDSliced}) is a promise I guess because I can use .then() on it...
            // and store.app sends request to another website from which it receives an object in return. 
            // (Variable store is from another file 'require()' above in my node app fie )
            promiseStack.push( store.app({id: appIDSliced}))

        });
    }


    // After pushing all promises into array, now i'm trying to resolve them using Promise.all
    Promise.all(promiseStack).then((responses) => {
        console.log("Dealing with responses")

        // Dealing with response (which is an object coming)
        responses.map(response => {
            var title = response.title
            var package_name = response.appId
            var appCategory = response.primaryGenre
            var appSize = parseFloat((response.size/1024)/1024).toFixed(2)
            var developerName = response.developer
            var developerWebsite = response.developerWebsite
            if (typeof developerWebsite == 'undefined') {
                developerWebsite = "N/A"
            }
            var appPrice = response.price
            var lastUpdated = response.updated
            var contentRating = response.contentRating
            if (typeof contentRating == 'undefined') {
                contentRating = "N/A"
            }
            var userRating = response.score
            if (typeof userRating == 'undefined') {
                userRating = "N/A"
            }
            var dataRow = [appID, title, package_name, appCategory, appSize, developerName, developerWebsite, appPrice, lastUpdated, contentRating, userRating]
            var dataToAdd = [dataRow];
            console.log("Appending now")

            // here i'm using google API to append that into my sheet on google
            authentication.authenticate().then((auth)=>{
                appendData(auth, dataToAdd);
            });
        })
    })
})
```

See the image below ... Those are the Errors I receive on my console
It keep logging 'sending' like for 80 secs and then I get error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" where I just get stuck for 2 mins and I keep pressing 'CTRL+C'.
[image: Error I receive on my console]

Thanks.

Comment: The error tells you that youre missing a *.catch*

Comment: But i was using a .catch() before and still get error similar to this..like request TIMEDOUT ( similar to that )  but I want to add delay and get rid of this error..

Comment: Thats not after pushing into array. because async program in loop you cannot trust having everything in an array. the `Promise.all` should be kept under `setTimeout(function() { }, 0);`. next is try `async.waterfall` like executing n numbers at a time , then proceed with attaching next. I can give you a sample idea in normal js. Implement accordingly.

Comment: @Priya Can you elaborate please ? i don't work with Promises much. :/

Comment: @Tayyab you can use a handy promise library bluebird.js for sending call's in series or parallel if there is no dependency

Comment: what does store.app(object) is returning..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async.each may be more appropriate in your case, check the [async.each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

Promise.all() doesnt seem right in this case, because method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects. [promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

I have tried to rewrite your code with async, there few assumptions I have made, this is the general example you probably may tune it for you logic.

```
var async = require('async');
fs.readFile('./google_apps/GAME_ACTION.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    async.each(obj['GAME_ACTION'], function(linksArray, callback){
        linksArray.forEach( function(link,) {
            var appID = link.match(/id=.*/g);
            var instr = appID.toString();

            var appIDSliced = instr.slice(3);

            console.log('sending') // for testing purpose
            // I am assuming that store.app() is asyncronous and get a callback
            store.app({id: appIDSliced}, function(err, response){
                if (err){
                    console.log('something bad happend');
                    callback();
                }
                else{
                        var title = response.title;
                        var package_name = response.appId;
                        var appCategory = response.primaryGenre;
                        var appSize = parseFloat((response.size/1024)/1024).toFixed(2);
                        var developerName = response.developer;
                        var developerWebsite = response.developerWebsite;
                        if (typeof developerWebsite == 'undefined') {
                            developerWebsite = "N/A"
                        }
                        var appPrice = response.price;
                        var lastUpdated = response.updated;
                        var contentRating = response.contentRating;
                        if (typeof contentRating == 'undefined') {
                            contentRating = "N/A"
                        }
                        var userRating = response.score;
                        if (typeof userRating == 'undefined') {
                            userRating = "N/A"
                        }
                        var dataRow = [appID, title, package_name, appCategory, appSize, developerName, developerWebsite, appPrice, lastUpdated, contentRating, userRating]
                        var dataToAdd = [dataRow];
                        console.log("Appending now");

                        authentication.authenticate().then((auth)=>{
                            appendData(auth, dataToAdd);
                        });
                    callback();
                }
            });
        });
    }, function (err) {

    });

});
```

Comment: I'm receiving ** UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]**

Comment: I think it is sending too much request, now I added catch method and receiving "Socket hung up" error

Comment: in this case you should use eachLimit(), which limits the number of concurrent requests. check the documentation: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pseudo recursive approach to slowly iterate one request after another:

```
var finished=new Promise(function(resolve){
   (function iterate( index=0) {
        var link=linksArray[index];
        var appID = link.match(/id=.*/g)
        var instr = appID.toString();
        var appIDSliced = instr.slice(3)
        var promise=store.app({id: appIDSliced});            
        promise.then(function(value){
             promiseStack.push(value);
             if(index<linksArray.length) return iterate(index+1);
             resolve(promiseStack);
        });
   })();
});

finished.then(function(responses){
 //your promise all code
});
```

Comment: You're not using any .catch()...it won't return any warning like it showing me in console?

Comment: And what about my two loops..for and foreach..should I use them inside "iterate" function? @Jonas-w

Comment: @tayyab this is not a copy-paste-run answer. You need to do some additional work to make it running. This just implements the forEach loop, it may work already but you could also implement the for loop like this...

Answer (score 0):

In `for loop` when you are pushing `store.app({id: appIDSliced})` & I guess it starts requesting the server thus in a burst mode.
`Promise.all` is resolving requests which is getting stuck.

Why not run `n numbers at a time` and make them follow till all server requests get completed. This way there will be delay between most of the requests as at any point of time there will be max 5 request will be running instead of burst execution.

```js
var functions = [];
var m;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  (function(j) {
    functions.push(function(callback) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
      var s = document.getElementById('here');
      var d = document.createElement('div');
      d.innerHTML = 'function : ' + j + ' executed after :' + random;
      s.appendChild(d);
      setTimeout(callback, random);
      // the above code executes something like xhr. remove it
      // here you can write your own statements
      // store.app({id: appIDSliced}, (err, response) => {
      //     responses.map(response => {
      //         var title = response.title
      //         {...}
      //         here i'm using google API to append that into my sheet on google
      //         authentication.authenticate().then((auth)=>{
      //            appendData(auth, dataToAdd);
      //         });
      //     });
      //     callback(); // you can add callback here after all your statements execution
      // });
    });
  })(i);
}

function exec(method) {
  // here method will call the below function which is in your case promise.
  // function(callback) {
  //     console.log(j);
  //     callback();
  // }
  method(function() {
    if (functions.length > m) {
      exec(functions[m]);
      m++;
    }
  });
}

// lets start only 5 at a time.
// first to complete next to start
// function number:    1      2     3     4     5
// completes :        2nd    3rd   1st   5th   4th
// start new :         7      8     6     10    9
setTimeout(function() {
  for (m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
    (function(m) {
      exec(functions[m]); // this will execute 1,2,3,4,5 function
      m++;
    })(m);
  }
}, 0);
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

Comment: No Promise.all doesn't hit the server at all it just wait for the promises sent earlier to be resolved

Comment: Yeah which in-turns does the call `store.app({id: appIDSliced})`. and in the problem statement it does in a burst mode.

Comment: it just observes the state of the promise request sent by store.app and when the state changes from pending to fullfilled it just triggers the call Promise.all it doesn't call the function which itself is returning promise

Answer (score 0):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function fetchData(objekt){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // api call and then 
      resolve(data);
  })
}

function doRequest(){

 Promise.coroutine(function *(){
        yield Promise.map(arr, fetchData);
 })()
 .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
}
```

A simple and shorter code with error handling.